# Error connecting my IBOutlets

Tags: xcode, swift, iboutlet

I have dragged my textbooks, labels etc from xcode with (hold down ctrl and drag them) (I done this so far in 3 viewcontrollers (which works)

But under my outlets it says: Viewcontroller does not have a label outlet named xxxx

I must have made some sort of common mistake here, but I seriously can't figure it out. It must be so simple, but I must have overlooked it. I tried researching for the problem here but without success so far. Anyone who know what it could be?
(I declared them all right after my class as I did in my other 3 viewcontrollers)

Edit: I uploaded how it looks too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you change the name of the outlet in your code file?

Comment: Not after I declared in after my ctrl drag.

Comment: Your target looks very strange. The IBOutlets are declared in a class named `level2stage1` but in InterfaceBuilder I can see `Level2 Stage1` and `level2Stage1Sh` something. Basically do not use space characters in class names and name classes always with a leading capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, click the label, then in your Utilities Menu on the far right are outlet connection tabs.  Check here and make sure the label is connected to the correct IBOutlet.

Comment: I have been there, thats how I could see there was a problem. I uploaded this menu with a picture. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your storyboard, right click on the orange icon on the left. It should allow you to disconnect the wrong outlet and reconnect to the right one.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Not too sure which icon. However it does not look like they are connected to a wrong outlet, it just looks like it can't register my outlets at all. Take a look at my updated pictures, if that helps! And thank you!